# Find distance inside on a Geopandas geometry edge, based on points and bearing

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to geo-process some data in a `.shp`, using Geopandas.

I would like to find a point in a geometry edge, given a bearing and an initial point inside of it.

How can I do this in an optimized way, since the algorithm will process a lot of iterations (approx.: ten per point)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to stick to lon/lat or you can switch to projected coordinate system like `UTM`; and also what exactly you mean by `bearing`. One possible way assuming projected coordinates and `compass bearing` (clock-wise degree from north: 0-360) is to draw a line in the direction of your bearing which is long enough to intersect with the Polygon and compute the coordinate of the intersection.

let's say we have a GeoDataFrame containing a Polygon of a district in Berlin:

```
berlin
# 
#    bbox_east  bbox_north  bbox_south  bbox_west   geometry    place_name
# 0 13.429402   52.540407   52.504037   13.36586    POLYGON ((389163.2519209321 5821873.324153989,...   Mitte, Berlin, Deutschland
```

compute the x/y of the centroid of the geometry(can be any point, here I use centroid for representing the idea):

```
x = berlin.centroid.geometry.item().x
y = berlin.centroid.geometry.item().y
```

Following function can compute coordinates of the new point:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing

def find_point(polygon, x, y , bearing):

    east, south, west, north = polygon.bounds
    line_length = max(abs(east-west), abs(north-south)) * 2

    new_x = x + (np.sin(np.deg2rad(bearing)) * line_length)
    new_y = y + (np.cos(np.deg2rad(bearing)) * line_length)

    l = LineString([[x,y], [new_x, new_y]])
    lr = LinearRing(polygon.exterior.coords)
    intersections = lr.intersection(l)

    return intersections.x, intersections.y
```

try it with our input data:

```
x_, y_ = find_point(berlin.geometry[0], x, y, 120)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

berlin.plot(ax=ax)
plt.scatter(x_, y_)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Indeed, the algorithm receive data in WGS84, then converts it to UTM. The bearing is exactly what you answered!
I'm trying to learn Python to geoprocess and make some computations for wind fetchs and wave-oriented analysis, and sometimes, it's hard to find information besides documentation from some libraries.
Thank you so much for the help!